# Subset and aggregate an original data.table based on a different column

Tags: r, data.table

This is surprisingly difficult, but I am trying to do what the title says, for example suppose I have a data table `dat` and I am trying to calculate the cumulative sum in a new column (from the 1st and 3rd, when it appears in the 2nd) of whatever group appears in the second column.

```
dat = data.table(A=c(1,2,3,1,4,5,1,2,3),B=c(1,1,1,NA,1,NA,2,NA,2),C=c(1,12,24.2,251,2,1,2,3,-1))
dat[,cumsum:=0]
```

So the data look like

```
   > dat
   A  B     C
1: 1  1   1.0
2: 2  1  12.0
3: 3  1  24.2
4: 1 NA 251.0
5: 4  1   2.0
6: 5 NA   1.0
7: 1  2   2.0
8: 2 NA   3.0
9: 3  2  -1.0
```

I want the output to be this:

```
> dat
   A  B     C cumsum
1: 1  1   1.0      1
2: 2  1  12.0      1
3: 3  1  24.2      1
4: 1 NA 251.0      0
5: 4  1   2.0      252
6: 5 NA   1.0      0
7: 1  2   2.0      12
8: 2 NA   3.0      0
9: 3  2  -1.0      15
```

Is there an efficient data table way to do this?  I could do this with loops but this would be quite slow, and I feel this must be doable in a more scalable way but I'm stuck.

Comment: @chinsoon12 fixed, you're right

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A possible approach to use non equi self join:

```
dat[, rn := .I]
dat[!is.na(B), cumsum := dat[.SD, on=.(A=B, rn<=rn), sum(x.C), by=.EACHI]$V1]
```

output:

```
   A  B     C cumsum rn
1: 1  1   1.0      1  1
2: 2  1  12.0      1  2
3: 3  1  24.2      1  3
4: 1 NA 251.0      0  4
5: 4  1   2.0    252  5
6: 5 NA   1.0      0  6
7: 1  2   2.0     12  7
8: 2 NA   3.0      0  8
9: 3  2  -1.0     15  9
```

data:

```
dat = data.table(A=c(1,2,3,1,4,5,1,2,3),B=c(1,1,1,NA,1,NA,2,NA,2),C=c(1,12,24.2,251,2,1,2,3,-1))
dat[,cumsum:=0]
```

---

edit: adding another approach inspired by Frank's answer

```
dat = data.table(A=c(1,2,3,1,4,5,1,2,3),B=c(1,1,1,NA,1,NA,2,NA,2),C=c(1,12,24.2,251,2,1,2,3,-1))
dat[, rn := .I][, cs := cumsum(C), A]
dat[, cumsum := 0][
    !is.na(B), cumsum :=  dat[.SD, on=.(A=B, rn), allow.cartesian=TRUE, roll=TRUE, x.cs]]
```

Comment: I tried this on my actual data and there seems to be an issue, so to replicate it I changed the data to this: 

`dat = data.table(A=c(1,2,3,1,4,5,1,2,3),B=c(1,1,1,NA,1,NA,2,NA,2),C=c(1,12,24.2,251,2,1,2,3,-1))`

The output turns out incorrect and I'm trying to figure out why.  I guess your solution requires that B cannot have more than one unique A?

Comment: what is the desired output in this case where there are more 1s in column B than in column A?

Comment: I think this is the most efficient answer after benchmarking!

Comment: Can someoen explain to me why this breaks down in grouping?  E.g. suppose I have a column D and I want to do the above operation for each D group... when I try the following I get an incorrect result: `dat = data.table(A=c(1,2,3,1,4,5,1,2,3),B=c(1,1,1,NA,1,NA,2,NA,2),C=c(1,12,24.2,251,2,1,2,3,-1),D=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2));
dat[, rn := 1:.N,by=D][, cs := cumsum(C), .(A,D)];
dat[, cumsum := 0][
  !is.na(B), cumsum :=  dat[.SD, on=.(A=B, rn,D), allow.cartesian=TRUE, roll=TRUE, x.cs]]`

Comment: posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57447378/non-equi-self-join-by-group-in-data-table

Answer (score 4):

Same idea as @chinsoon's answer, but with a rolling join:

```
dat[, rn := .I]
mDT = dat[.(setdiff(B, NA)), on=.(A), .(rn, v = cumsum(C)), by=.EACHI]

dat[, cumsum := 0]
dat[!is.na(B), cumsum := mDT[.SD, on=.(A=B, rn), roll=TRUE, x.v]]

   A  B     C cumsum rn
1: 1  1   1.0      1  1
2: 2  1  12.0      1  2
3: 3  1  24.2      1  3
4: 1 NA 251.0      0  4
5: 4  1   2.0    252  5
6: 5 NA   1.0      0  6
7: 1  2   2.0     12  7
8: 2 NA   3.0      0  8
9: 3  2  -1.0     15  9
```

For every value of `B`, `mDT` has corresponding rows of `A` with row number and cumsum. We look up the latest value of the cumsum by rolling to the most recent row number.

---

Here's another rolling join approach suggested by @chinsoon:

```
dat[, rn := .I]
dat[, cs := cumsum(C), by=A]

dat[, cumsum := 0]
dat[ !is.na(B), cumsum := dat[.SD, on=.(A=B, rn), allow.cartesian=TRUE, roll=TRUE, x.cs]]
```

Comment: this will be faster. and for the first cumsum maybe `dat[, rn := .I][, cs := cumsum(C), A];
dat[, cumsum := 0][
    !is.na(B), cumsum :=  dat[.SD, on=.(A=B, rn), allow.cartesian=TRUE, roll=TRUE, x.cs]]`

Answer (score 2):

Not a `data.table` solution but one way using `dplyr` could be

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
   mutate(row = row_number(), 
   cumsum = purrr::map2_dbl(B, row, ~sum(C[A == .x & row <= .y], na.rm = TRUE))) %>%
   select(-row)

#  A  B     C cumsum
#1 1  1   1.0      1
#2 2  1  12.0      1
#3 3  1  24.2      1
#4 1 NA 251.0      0
#5 4  1   2.0    252
#6 5 NA   1.0      0
#7 1  2   2.0     12
#8 2 NA   3.0      0
#9 3  2  -1.0     15
```

Not sure if it would be any efficient to calculate `sum` only for non-NA  values of  `B`

```
dat %>%
  mutate(row = row_number(), 
         cumsum = ifelse(is.na(B), 0, 
          purrr::map2_dbl(B, row, ~sum(C[A == .x & row <= .y], na.rm = TRUE)))) %>%
  select(-row)
```

Comment: Testing this out, if I had a fourth column D that I wanted this done for each group in D, I would just add dat %>% group_by(D) %>% ... right? (Sorry I'm pretty new to dplyr)